# Corrosion dripping down water heater

Tags: plumbing

I noticed this on mywater heater and was wondering if that’s a sign that it needs to be replaced soon?

[image: hot water heater,]

Comment: Where does it start (thus, where is it leaking **from?**)

Comment: This photo is like showing your mechanic a trail of oil on the road and asking them to fix your car based on that. Show us the source. Also, with that much gunk buildup it's been leaking for a good while. In fact, I doubt that this is even a water supply leak. Something else is going on. That's nasty.

Answer (score 1):

A definite maybe.

Hard to tell for sure without more details, particularly a picture of the top. But that is typical for a slow leak. If that leak is from one of the pipes then it may be fixable. If it is from the seam where the top meets the cylinder then it is most likely not. If the water heater is at least 10 years old then I would recommend starting the process for getting it replaced before it becomes an emergency (been there, twice).

Comment: Looks more like a leak from gas flue/chimney to me.

Comment: Might be a leaky (or needs expansion tank it doesn't have) T/P valve, not properly routed to elsewhere, too.